# Solr edismax qf and pf defaults not working to boost fields

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I am attempting to set up a request handler that will boost certain fields by different amounts. I have the following request handler.

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <str name="start">0</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="defType">edismax</str>
   <str name="qf">
      title^50.0 searchTitle^7.0 keywords^5.0 content^1.0 text^1.0
   </str>
   <str name="pf">
      title^50.0 searchTitle^7.0 keywords^5.0 content^1.0 text^1.0
   </str>
   <str name="df">text</str>
 </lst>    
</requestHandler>
```

However, the fields aren't being boosted correctly, if at all. I noticed that documents with the search term in the `title` field aren't appearing any higher than documents with the search term in the `text` field. Arbitrarily re-arranging the weights produces the same document order each time.

When I go into the solr web interface/admin UI and do a search I get the same results. However, if I explicitly check the `edismax` checkbox and enter the field-boost data in the `qf` and `pf` boxes I get the results and the weighting I would expect.

In fact, I also just tried changing the `rows` value to 5 and still received the same result. It looks like my queries aren't being handled by the `/select` handler, even though that is what I choose both in the solr Admin UI and when I create the `HttpSolrServer` object to do the queries from the server.

I am using solr v4.8.0.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check setting in solrconfig for

```
<requestDispatcher handleSelect="false" >
```

If you want to use select as a requesthandler, this needs to be

```
 <requestDispatcher handleSelect="true" >
```